# Brakes still smoke in hot weather despite replacing a plethora of parts

Tags: brakes, dodge, caravan, weather-dependent

This is a 1999 Dodge Caravan 6 cylinder 3.3 FWD.

When driving in cool weather the van drives fine. When driving in warmer weather the brake gets hard and acceleration is little. The driver-side front wheel gets scalding-hot and starts to smoke.

I have changed the following items with new parts: brake pads, calipers, rotors, ball joints, inner and outer tie rods, the hose from cooling fan unit to the engine, sending unit, oil changed, inspection a couple new tires.

This still happens, so what could be wrong? The driver front caliper was seized up so I put another new caliper on it. The vehicle was driven a short distance with the emergency brake on 10 months ago, back brakes were slightly caught for a bit.

I haven't had any trouble with them, although once in a very blue moon I can hear a slight catch from the rear. Please help.

Comment: get brake fluid replaced yet.? . metallic parts can be measured in fluid with a megaohm meter

Comment: Recheck the parts replaced. Probably the brake caliper, pads and rotor. Next the wheel bearing on the same side. Did you actually perform the work or do a function check post-repair? Sounds like you enlisted a shop, and they replaced a lot of irrelevant parts (tie-rods, tires!) and still failed to fix your complaint. I'd sue them but hey, IANAL.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem with several vehicles in my time...it was the soft rubber flexible lines that went bad, it allows fluid to the calipers but because of denigration wont allow it to go back when you release the brakes, the lines between the caliper and hard line are the soft brake hoses.

My son just had the same problem he replaced all that you have and still had the problem then he asked me I  told him what it was and he replaced and it fixed the problem.

He wished he asked me before he spent all the money on the other parts. Hope this helps, also after seeing that you replace all those other parts i wont give instructions.

Answer (score -1):

It seems obvious that the driver-side front brake caliper is not functioning like it should, as it still does not release properly. Disassemble the caliper and check proper movement of parts, especially check if the brake piston is not seized. It may require some force but you should be able to push it back a little by hand. If it is seized then there are brake overhaul kits available with a new brake piston and rubber seal ring.

Also you did not mention that you changed the brake fluid. This is essential because older fluid contains moisture, which can expand when its warm.

Comment: They replaced the calipers, no change.